# XML Comments Format Poorly in Swagger UI

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using Swashbuckle to setup Swagger UI and have it display my XML Comments on my operations.

When I do this, they end up looking very squished.  Here is an example of what it looks like without comments:

[image: Looks Good But No Comments]

Here is what it looks like with comments:

[image: Has Comments But Method Name is Squished]

**Is there someway to get Swagger UI to allocate more space for the Operation Name?**

Comment: Ye @Helen is right about the `remarks` but if you want to tweak more you can inject CSS to suit your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<summary>` is supposed to be a short summary, like "Create a foo" or "Return a foo by ID". Long descriptions containing usage details should go to `<remarks>`. `<remarks>` corresponds to OpenAPI `description` field; Swagger UI displays these descriptions in expanded operations. These descriptions can be formatted using Markdown for rich text representation.

```csharp
/// <summary>
/// Create a foo
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
/// sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
/// Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
/// nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
/// </remarks>
```